# Is it possible to create a DateFormatter which converts a two-digit year into a four-digit year?

Tags: java, calendar

In my Java application I use a `DateFormat` instance to parse date inputs.

```
DateFormat fmt;
fmt = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.DEFAULT)  // dd.MM.yyyy for de_DE
```

The problem is that the user insists to enter dates in the form `31.12.11`.

Unfortunately this is parsed to `31.12.11`. (`0011-12-31` in ISO format) Instead I want the parsed date to become `31.12.2011` (`2011-12-31` in ISO format).

Can I modify the date format to somehow parse inputs that way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You will have to parse with a format of dd.MM.yy and re-format with a format of yyyy-MM-dd

```
DateFormat sdfp = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.mm.yy");
Date d = sdfp.parse(input);
DateFormat sdff = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String date = sdff.format(d);
```

See the Java API for more info on setting patterns.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: It seems my question was a little ambiguous. I don't want to have a String representation in ISO format, I want the date to have the correct year (2011 instead of 11, i.e. +2.000 years)

Comment: i'm not sure how java will take 11 as 2011 and not as 1911 or anyother value.

Comment: @asgs: The link josh.trow provided, answers that question at least for `SimpleDateFormat`. The creation time of the instance is used to heuristically choose the century.

Comment: `For parsing with the abbreviated year pattern ("y" or "yy"), SimpleDateFormat must interpret the abbreviated year relative to some century. It does this by adjusting dates to be within 80 years before and 20 years after the time the SimpleDateFormat  instance is created.` - This is fantastic. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: The answer is right, but I'd use SHORT instead of "dd.mm.yy".

Comment: @DR Whoops, thanks for the correction I forgot how to spell apparently :)

Answer (score 5):

Your solution here is sufficiently simple as to allow for the use of SimpleDateFormat, which includes the method `set2DigitYearStart(Date startDate)`. Perhaps it looks something like this.

```
String userInput = "31.12.11";
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yy");
format.set2DigitYearStart(new GregorianCalendar(2001,1,1).getTime());
Date userEnteredDate = format.parse(userInput, 1); // parsed to 2011-12-31
```

Comment: Calling `set2DigitYearStart` only overrides the 80-20 heuristic. The actual solution is using the `yy` pattern rather than `yyyy`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could parse using DateFormat.SHORT instead of DEFAULT.

Or possibly, try to parse with SHORT, and then try other formats if that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse this date using SimpleDateFormat but how you will determine that was 1911 or 2011 or anything else. you should use year format as yyyy.

Answer (score 1):

If you use GWT, you don't have access to SimpleDateFormat, so here is some code to do it manually:

```
String[] parts = dateText.split(" ");

// Convert 2 digit date to 4 digits
if (parts.length == 3 && parts[2].length() == 2) {
    int year = Integer.valueOf(parts[2]);

    // Allow 5 years in the future for a 2 digit date
    if (year + 100 > new Date().getYear()+5) {
        year = year + 1900;
    }
    else {
        year = year + 2000;
    }
    dateText = parts[0] + " " + parts[1] + " " + String.valueOf(year);
}
```

This assumes you have validated that the dateText is separated with spaces.

Answer (score 1):

An approximation:

```
int twoDigitYear = 11;
int fourDigitYear = 0;
DateTime now = new DateTime();

if (twoDgYear + 2000 > now().getYear()) {
   fourDigitYear = twoDigitYear + 1900;
}else{
   fourDigitYear = twoDigitYear + 2000;
}
```

May or may not fit your need...